# Converting strings to integers the right way

Tags: c++

I would like to verify that strings are valid integers. I could just use 64 bits integers and functions like `std::stoull` or `std::stoll` but I can't verify if the value is between a given range.

Example, I want an integer between 0 and UINT64_MAX. If the string is `"-1"`, I can convert it to a `long long` and I'll know it's negative. However, if the string is above the maximum of **signed long long** (usually `INT64_MAX`), the overflow makes it negative again while the string was a positive integer.

A friend first advised me to check for a minus sign but I didn't like this solution, then I thought about using a double, however I know that comparisons using doubles can be tricky so that's why I'm unsure about this solution.

```
template <typename T>
inline bool is_between(const string &str,
                       T min = numeric_limits<T>::min(),
                       T max = numeric_limits<T>::max()) noexcept
{
    try {
        double value = stod(str);

        if (value < min || value > max)
            return false;
    } catch (...) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is this function safe? Because I'm afraid that a string of "1" could return a double value of "0.9999999999", then it would not fit in an interval between 1 and 100.

Then we can use the function like this:

```
cout << is_between<uint16_t>("0") << endl;
cout << is_between<uint16_t>("65535") << endl;
cout << is_between<uint16_t>("65535", 0, 2000) << endl;
cout << is_between<uint16_t>("-1") << endl;
cout << is_between<uint16_t>("800000") << endl;
```

Comment: Why not convert `min` and `max` into strings and do string comparison?

Comment: Does [std::stoull](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) not throw an exception?

Comment: @IInspectable If I remember right `std::stoull` does not throw if the input is negative.

Comment: No, `std::stoull` does not throw an exception when invoked with "-1".

Comment: @NathanOliver: The documentation seems to agree with you. Talking about a specification that completely avoids taking the route of least surprise...

Comment: On input of "-1" `strtoull()` returns ULLONG_MAX and sets `errno` to ERANGE. I don't like OP's function. What is the real purpose of mixing so many things (suppressing exceptions, converting and comparing in a single function, using C functions instead of C++) like this?

Comment: Hmm, I've just tried with strtoull, it does not set errno to ERANGE on my machine, not on ideone neither : http://ideone.com/cMFrbu

Comment: Careful with that, Markand. Unable to reproduce Dúthomhas's claim on VS 2010 and 2015, or on GCC 4.8 and 4.9

Answer (score 2):

Your function is safe from the error you describe because small enough integer numbers can be represented exactly with floating point numbers. Hence, the conversion of `1` cannot be `0.99999` because they are different numbers if `0.99999` can be represented in doubles. The conversion of `0.99999` to `1` is possible.

However, if you have large enough number, the limit checking does not work, because 64bit double precision has less bits (usually 54, but this is not defined in standard) for the fraction part  than a 64bit integer. E.g., output of a following program is `1` and not `0` as if it would be with a higher precision numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  long long v=(1l << 54) +1;
  std::cout << v-static_cast<long long>(std::stod(std::to_string(v))) << std::endl;
}
```

If you really need numbers close to `UINT64_MAX` it's better to use some library like [Boost multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html). It has an arbitrary precision integer `cpp_int`, which can be constructed from a `std::string`.

Comment: How is that possible? The maximum double is much higher than the maximum of a 64 bit unsigned. Your program also output 0 on [ideone](http://ideone.com/adPr0v)

Comment: Is using a `long double` and `stold` a valid solution? It seems to work on this [code](http://ideone.com/LVxweZ)

Comment: @mark the maximum of double is larger, but because some of the bits goes to representing the exponent it cannot represent all the number 64bit integer can. In other words, for large enough doubles the difference between two consecutive numbers is larger than one. There is something strange with ideone. The result of  `long long v=(1l << 54) +1;` is `1`. If you just substitute the result of that calculation to it it seems to give what I expect. See [ideone](http://ideone.com/k3aoHP). If the `long double` is 128 bits and the mantissa is more than 64bits in your system it will work.